# How to execute action on destination of copy-paste, move and drag-and-drop operations

Tags: winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

In my Shell Namespace Extension I want to execute some action on the files that user has copied from it immediately after the copy process. It is a resource consuming process, so I would really prefer to first copy a file and only after that start processing it rather than present already processed items to the user.

Implementing a [Drop Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-drop-handlers) approach on `Folder` and `Directory` Classes works, but it appears to be too frustrating for end-user (to remember that items should be copied only with right-click drag-and-drop and not via `Ctrl`+`C` / `Ctrl`+`V` or any other mean).

So I am trying to find a way to execute this action right after "normal" copy.

Both `IDataObject` and `ITransferSource` interfaces do not provide any information about the destination of the data except for `ITransferSource::MoveItem`. I know it is done intentionally on the `IDataObject` since target could be whatever and the source should not know about it.

So for my specific task I think I need to find answers for following questions:

1. Is it possible to know from within `IDataObject` "who" is the receiver of the data: Explorer or any other application? I guess we can skip special Explorer-like cases like TotalCommander.
2. If it is somehow possible to know that Drop Target is an Explorer window - is it possible to know the destination folder?
3. Is it possible to know if the copy process with `IDataObject` ended successfully (except for tracking if `IStream` was read till the very end)?
4. Is it possible to know the destination for the `ITransferSource::OpenItem`?
5. Is it possible to know if the copy process with `ITransferSource::OpenItem` ended successfully?

Comment: Have you read [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios) yet?

Comment: 1) No 2) No 3) maybe have the `IDataObject` accept [`CFSTR_PERFORMEDDROPEFFECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cfstr_performeddropeffect) from the target 4) No 5) I don't know, but I'm guessing No.

Comment: Source and target are not meant to communicate directly, unless they know each other (and can use special IDataObject formats, etc.). In the general case, only the IStream approach can give "some" level of knowledge, however depending on application, they can use Read or CopyTo (Office apps do that) and obviously, nothing is guaranteed in the way they use it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, that was the starting point. But anyway thanks for putting this link here since it is fundamental. In my case I am just trying to find some tricky way to bypass limits of this `IDataObject` fundamentals where source and target do not know anything about each other.

Comment: @SimonMourier that is exactly the case I was thinking about: I have seen that while drag-and-drop operation Explorer (or whoever is controlling that) communicates with `IDataObject` through `DragContext` format (carrying `IStream`).